# Unable to load Windows and unable to mount Windows partitions (probably corrupted )

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, boot-repair

It is a kind of messed up situation.
I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on Windows 8 which didn't display Ubuntu.
I then tried Boot-Repair by opening **Try Ubuntu without installing**.
Here is the URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6555659 
At this instant I was unable to load Windows.
Then I changed the BIOS setting from *UEFI* to *Legacy* which on restarting displayed the message `No operating system found`.

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 again.

Here are my problems:

1. I am unable to load Windows. (It is asking for recovery media which I don't have right now.)
2. In Ubuntu I am unable to mount any Windows partitions.

Error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda8 at /media/dew/Songs, Videos & Movies: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda8" "/media/dew/Songs, Videos & Movies"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda8': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I guess that Windows was hibernated or didn't shutdown properly. I can't open Windows again to ensure that it is properly shutdown (as mentioned earlier I don't have recovery media). I am happy to use Ubuntu for a while until I get my recovery media, but meanwhile is there any way to mount my Windows partitions?

Comment: `sudo mount -t "ntfs" -o "ro,uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda8" "/media/dew/Songs, Videos & Movies"`

Comment: fuse: failed to access mountpoint /media/dew/Songs, Videos & Movies: No such file or directory , In the folder /media/dew/ there are no directories . It is completely empty

Comment: `mkdir -p '/media/dew/Songs, Videos & Movies'` then repeat.

Comment: I created a folder there . but it is still not accessible.*fuse: failed to access mountpoint /media/dew/Songs, Videos & Movies: No such file or directory*

Comment: `The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda8': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown` I tried the same command with -ro instead of -o. then the following error was seen. `fuse: failed to access mountpoint /media/dew/Songs, Videos & Movies: No such file or directory

Comment: no, not instead of `-o`, the `-o`tells that the following text block will be options. And we wanna give it the additional option read only, `ro,`, as it will let you mount the partition.

Comment: Not a duplicate since this question is asking how to mount the volume without a working Windows install.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ntfs-3g has **an option** to deal with this kind of situation: `remove_hiberfile` (see [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man8/ntfs-3g.8.html)).

The man page goes on to warn about the **consequences** of using that option.

> Please note, means that the saved Windows  session  will  be  completely lost. Use this option under your own responsibility.

If those are acceptable for you, you can try to mount your partition by adding `remove_hiberfile` to your `-o` string.

Comment: `sudo mount -t "ntfs" -o "ro,remove_hiberfile,uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda8" "/media/dew/Songs, Videos & Movies"`
Is this how you add remove_hiberfile ?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with doing it that way.

Comment: I changed the name of partition from "Songs, Videos & Movies" to "Songs". then it worked it fine

Comment: It seems that I need to do this every time I restart my lappy ?

Comment: @RakeshGodhala, no you should only need to do it once as long as you aren't booting back into Windows.