# How do you mount a partition locked by Windows hibernation without dual boot

Tags: mount, windows-8, partitioning

I've installed Ubuntu on a friend's laptop, completely replacing Windows 8. He has a backup ntfs partition that I left untouched after the operating system was replaced. I get an error in Nautilus when I try to mount; it's because of Windows hibernation from what I've read. The problem is, I didn't keep the Windows partition.

Is there a way to mount and unlock the partition without booting to Windows 8?

*I thought to post this question even when I'm well aware of that one referred to as the original because **there it assumes that dual boot is still available.** The top answer shows that, and closes off responses for my situation. I needed an answer for when the Windows boot is no longer available.*

Comment: try the third option in this http://askubuntu.com/a/145904/202806

Comment: If it is not the hibernation, it could also be that it needs chkdsk which can only be run from a Windows repairCD or flash drive. Any resize of a NTFS partition sets the chkdsk flag which also like hibernation prevents it from being mounted by the Linux NTFS driver.

Comment: @Avinash I want to get rid of the hibernation lock for good since I don't have the Windows 8 installation anymore. The script solution you pointed to doesn't appear to fix that.

Comment: @kelvinilla did you try remove_hiberfile option of `ntfs-3g`?

Comment: @kelvinilla see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/389237/unable-to-load-windows-and-unable-to-mount-windows-partitions-probably-corrupte/389244#389244

Comment: @Avinash I haven't tried that. I don't have a hold of the computer until Thursday. Would that command work with Windows 8 hibernation? Can you give an example usage of the syntax?

Comment: yes,mount the windows partition and run the ntfs-3g remove-hiberfile option.

Comment: @Avinash Mounting via `ntfs-3g` even with the `remove-hiberfile` option gives the same error as mounting it with defaults. In the end, I just backed-up the partition then wiped it. Thanks nonetheless.